# Making API call twice with volley in an activity...Good Practice?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-adapter, android-glide

I am fetching data about some pokemon and want to also grab their images and glide in the same activity. The images can not be fetched directly, I have to get the url to images from the pokemon url object.

I mean I have to first fetch pokemons with `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/limit?=10`  from the response I get each pokemon images url by id `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1`

I was able to do this successfully in my adapter but wondering if it is best practice as I am afraid of it lagging if the number is larger

### Adapter is below

```
class ApiAdapter (internal var activity: MainActivity):RecyclerView.Adapter<ApiAdapter.ApiViewHolder>(){

    private val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)


    init{

        loadData()
    }
    val dataInstance = ArrayList<DataClass>()
    private fun loadData(){

        val url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=5"

        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            Response.Listener { response ->

                try {
                    val jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results")
                    lateinit var name:String
                    lateinit var pokeUrl: String
                    lateinit var jsonCities: JSONArray
                    for(i in 0 until jsonArray.length()){
                        val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        name = jsonObject.getString("name")
                        pokeUrl = jsonObject.getString("url")


                        dataInstance.add(DataClass(name, pokeUrl))

                    }


                    notifyDataSetChanged()

                }
                catch (error: JSONException){
                    error.printStackTrace()
                }


            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                // TODO: Handle error

                Log.e("Api", "error: $error")

            }

        )
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }




    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ApiViewHolder{
        val layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.data_row, parent, false)
        return ApiViewHolder(layout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:ApiViewHolder, position:Int){

        val current = dataInstance.get(position)

        holder.name.text = current.name


        fun loadImageData(){

            val url = current.url

            val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                Response.Listener { response ->

                    try {
                        val jsonResponse = response.getJSONObject("sprites")
                        val picUrl = jsonResponse.optString("front_default")

                        Glide.with(activity).load(picUrl).into(holder.image)

//                        notifyDataSetChanged()
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "res: $picUrl", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    catch (error: JSONException){
                        error.printStackTrace()
                    }

                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->


                    Log.e("Api", "error: $error")

                }

            )
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
        }

        loadImageData()


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataInstance.size
    }

    class ApiViewHolder(dataView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(dataView){


        internal var name = dataView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
        internal var image = dataView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.pokemon_image)

    }
}
```

Perhaps there is a better way to get around this. Your advice will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few general notes and suggestions:

- You are triggering an API call from `onBindViewHolder`. This will trigger it every time the view is bound after recycling.  You will need to either pull it out of the adapter, or implement some caching.  In general, never put API within an Adapter without caching, it's a recipe for disaster.
- You are calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` from within the adapter.  This is also generally considered bad practice.  The workflow should be the adapter takes in only view state data, then applies that view state data to it's children via an external `notifyDatasetChanged`.

For your situation specifically though, you do not really need an extra API call at all to get the pokemon's image.  All pokemon from the PokeAPI use the same image URL format, for example:
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/4.png`

If you simply replace the number `4` in that URL with the ID of the pokemon, you can avoid having to make that extra API call and just pass that manual URL direct to the adapter.  Then grab the full pokemon object in the full details activity or fragment. 
 Just an idea.